# DataContractSerializer, xsd and response xml

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

I'm about to integrate a third party SOAP service in my application. I have no control over this service, I've just got a bounch of .xsd files, a wsdl file and some example responses. I'm using the default way to generating a proxy client in Visual Studio. I've added the same wsdl to Soap UI along with the response xml.

The thing is that when I receive the response in my application, some of the values are null. By adding a class implementing `IEndpointBehavior and IClientMessageInspector` to the service client, I can see in the method `AfterReceiveReply` the expected xml response. Some of the values in the proxy object is null.

Inspecting the objects in the service definition, I can see that the `Order` attribute is marked on the types. For instance:

```
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
   public string name { .......
```

My first thought was that the response xml did not contain all of the expect elements and in the correct order as described in the .xsd file.

Looking at the relevant .xsd file, elements are defined like this:

```
<xs:element name="name" type="MyTypeHere" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Some documentation</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

Does this element need to be there in the response when marked as

```
minOccurs="0"
```

Or will the value only be null? For obvious reason I cannot post the wsdl or the .xsd files here..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Is there actually a problem?

Comment: @CharlesMager If an element in the xsd is marked with minOccurs="0", does it need to be in the response xml? Or will the value just be empty, but the tag still there? Understandable? Thanks.

Comment: `minOccurs=0` is fairly self explanatory. The minimum number of times the element needs to occur is 0. So no, it does not need to be in the response; it is optional.

Comment: @CharlesMager and what will then happen to the Order attribute generated by Visual Studio/svcutil? Struggling with null values, but the raw xml contains the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Do not bother about the null values. As long as they filled out the values you need you are good to go.

Sometimes they want one type of response to all types of requests. They tend to add fields that are not needed for other request types.

Comment: The null values has to have value, they appear in the raw xml response.

Comment: If that is the case then you need to contact the administrator of that service. That is a programming error.